# Issue using EmbeddedService[] for Youtube

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I'm having trouble embedding youtube videos in the Wolfram Cloud using Mathematica.  It doesn't work.  Any ideas how to fix this?  Or a workaround?

The function EmbeddedServices[] in the documentation states "Embed a video from YouTube. Here the output is shown as it appears in the Wolfram Cloud":

```
EmbeddedService[{"YouTube", "W4KH1Jw6HBI”}]
```

[image]